# PhpStorm - Synology - CLI Interpreter - Updates

Tags: php, command-line-interface, phpstorm, interpreter, synology

I want to create a new project in PhpStorm, but I can't figure out why I can't add a PHP Interpreter in PhpStorm 2020.1.1.

First some info:
All is starting from my Synology NAS DS415+ with latest DSM 6.2.3-25426.
Installed on NAS:

- Web Station
- MariaDB 10
- phpMyAdmin
- PHP 7.2
- PHP 7.3
- Apache HTTP Server 2.4

SSH-connection is added successfully in PhpStorm.
Z-driveletter is /web-folder.

So, first things first. I created a `/composer` folder inside my `/web` folder. Composer.phar is selected in path as you can see.

[image: New Project]

Then I would select a PHP Interpreter.

[image: Php Interpreter]

I will add a new interpreter, so I click on +-sign.
Because of all is installed on my NAS, I select "From Docker, Vagrant, VM, WSL,**Remote**,..."
Then I select SSH because I can access my NAS through SSH.

Within SSH configuration I select mine. Test Connection => Successfully connected!

[image: SSH configuration]

Now, I needed to enter the PHP interpreter path. I've searched on my NAS and found these paths:

- /volume1/@appstore/PHP7.3/usr/local/bin/php73
- /volume1/@appstore/PHP7.2/usr/local/bin/php72

However, I can NOT browse to these paths or enter one of these paths in the input-field.

Do or did I something wrong?

Could anyone help to get this works?

**Update - 06/23/2020**

I've created a phpinfo file.
What I've see is that my PHP.ini file path = C:\Windows.
I think that's not the intention? I need my NAS PHP.ini!
How can I configure this?

[image: PHP Info]

**Update - 06/27/2020**

I've created a log file that you can find over here:

```
2020-06-27 13:41:49,202 [13856671]  DEBUG - sh.config.OpenSSHConfigService - Failed to parse OpenSSH configuration file: C:\Users\User\.ssh\config 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\User\.ssh\config (System can't find specified file)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:112)
    at java.base/java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:60)
    at com.intellij.ssh.config.OpenSSHConfig.parseFile(OpenSSHConfig.java:91)
    at com.intellij.ssh.config.OpenSSHConfigService.a(OpenSSHConfigService.kt:57)
    at com.intellij.ssh.config.OpenSSHConfigService.a(OpenSSHConfigService.kt:52)
    at com.intellij.ssh.config.OpenSSHConfigService.getConfig(OpenSSHConfigService.kt:29)
    at com.intellij.ssh.RemoteCredentialsUtil.connectionBuilder(remoteCredentialsUtil.kt:33)
    at com.intellij.ssh.RemoteCredentialsUtil.connectionBuilder$default(remoteCredentialsUtil.kt:27)
    at com.intellij.ssh.RemoteCredentialsUtil.connectionBuilder(remoteCredentialsUtil.kt)
    at com.intellij.ssh.ui.unified.SshCredentialsEditorEx$1.a(SshCredentialsEditorEx.java:68)
    at com.intellij.util.RunnableCallable.call(RunnableCallable.java:20)
    at com.intellij.util.RunnableCallable.call(RunnableCallable.java:11)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.call(ApplicationImpl.java:255)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2020-06-27 13:41:58,050 [13865519]  DEBUG - ellij.ssh.SshConnectionService - Creating sftp channel within SshjSshConnection(<crc32=1xag9ud>@<crc32=hwmx1i>)@54eb5487 
2020-06-27 13:41:58,061 [13865530]   WARN - net.schmizz.concurrent.Promise - <<chan#16 / open>> woke to: Opening `session` channel failed: open failed 
2020-06-27 13:41:58,061 [13865530]  DEBUG - ellij.ssh.SshConnectionService - Creating sftp channel within SshjSshConnection(<crc32=1xag9ud>@<crc32=hwmx1i>)@2c5f9c31 
2020-06-27 13:41:58,062 [13865531]   INFO - .channel.direct.SessionChannel - Will request `sftp` subsystem 
2020-06-27 13:41:58,069 [13865538]   WARN - net.schmizz.concurrent.Promise - <<chan#6 / chanreq for subsystem>> woke to: net.schmizz.sshj.connection.ConnectionException: Request failed 
2020-06-27 13:41:58,069 [13865538]   INFO - tesdk.ui.CreateRemoteSdkUIUtil - Request failed 
com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.CustomFileSystemException: Request failed
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.remotesdk.RemoteSdkUtil.checkInterpreterAndCreateHelpersDir(RemoteSdkUtil.java:360)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.remotesdk.RemoteSdkUtil$1.lambda$run$0(RemoteSdkUtil.java:297)
    at com.intellij.util.RunnableCallable.call(RunnableCallable.java:20)
    at com.intellij.util.RunnableCallable.call(RunnableCallable.java:11)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.call(ApplicationImpl.java:255)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.intellij.ssh.SshTransportException: Request failed
    at com.intellij.ssh.impl.sshj.SshjSshConnection.openChannel(SshjSshConnection.kt:52)
    at com.intellij.ssh.impl.SshConnection.openChannel(SshConnection.kt:67)
    at com.intellij.ssh.SshConnectionService.sftp(SshConnectionService.kt:171)
    at com.intellij.ssh.ConnectionBuilder.openSftpChannel(ssh.kt:141)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.remotesdk.RemoteSdkUtil.checkInterpreterAndCreateHelpersDir(RemoteSdkUtil.java:356)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: net.schmizz.sshj.connection.ConnectionException: Request failed
    at net.schmizz.sshj.connection.channel.AbstractChannel.gotResponse(AbstractChannel.java:405)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.connection.channel.AbstractChannel.handle(AbstractChannel.java:192)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.connection.ConnectionImpl.handle(ConnectionImpl.java:130)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl.handle(TransportImpl.java:500)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Decoder.decodeMte(Decoder.java:159)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Decoder.decode(Decoder.java:79)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Decoder.received(Decoder.java:231)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Reader.run(Reader.java:59)
```

Maybe that could be more informative.

Comment: Try adding a deployment configuration that would use this SSH config and check if you can actually browse the filesystem there. There's a chance that the NAS SSH implementation is limited, and despite Check Connection being successful, the actual browsing might not be working.

Comment: There is a deployment configuration that I've used. I can browse into all shared folders on my NAS. Can I found the PHP interpreter path somewhere in there? Or do I need to create that?

Comment: Does `php -v` work in the server's SSH session? If not, does `/volume1/@appstore/PHP7.3/usr/local/bin/php73 -v` work? If it does, you can just create a symlink to the latter in `/usr/bin` or in any other path that is in $PATH

Comment: @Eugene Yes, php -v work in SSH.
PHP 7.3.16 (cli) (built: Jun  2 2020 11:39:19) ( NTS )